# What are possible breaking changes can happen in dot net assembly

Tags: .net-assembly

I am learning about the .NET assembly version number. While looking for when to change assembly version number, I came across the term breaking change. I believe "breaking change" is a vast area, and I know few possiblities of breaking changes:

- Interface changed
- Exposed method changed

Please help me to identify any other possiblities that can be considered breaking changes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I can give an exhaustive list, but whenever you change the semantics or functionality of a visible type or type member (like method, constructor, property, event, and so on), that will be a breaking change.

A type or member is "visible" outside your assembly if it is `public` or `protected` (including `protected internal`), and all containing types (classes and structs that this program element "sits" inside) are also `public` or `protected`.

Also, if you change the "formal" appearance of a member, like changing a field into a property, or changing the (return) type of a method, property, event, and so on, or changing the signature of a method, including changing optional parameters or their default values. Adding a new overload to an existing method could in some cases be a breaking change, like if a call by the consuming code could possibly become ambiguous.

Changing in any way the "fields" (named constants) of an enum, whether renaming or changing the order, is a breaking change, like changing the value of a `const` field.

According to [.NET and Compatibility: Breaking Changes in a Managed World (Kit George)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/04/06/405982.aspx), there was once a document from Microsoft "defining" this term. Don't know if it is still out there, or if it is useful.